# Compressing multi-spectral image

Tags: python, image, matrix, lossless-compression

I need to compress multispectral images in a **lossless** way, all the classical compression algorithms (Zip,Rar,Gzip,Deflate etc...) don't give very good results, with compression rates of approximately 1.2 , does anyone know a specially made algorithm that can compress this particular type of images with compression rates of at least 1.5 ?

Possibly I would like to use the algorithm in python, my matrix containing the spectral values is contained in a numpy file

I have tried many algorithms, but none gave the desired result; unfortunately, I cannot implement one by myself ad hoc.
The matrix used consists of 16bit unsigned integers.

This is a small part of the array, to give an example of the type of data inside, they are 16-bit unsigned integers.

[The data in .npy and .txt format](https://file.io/eHMJQvWWGcCA)

Min value: 0
Max value: 65.536

To date, the most efficient algorithm has been Jpeg2000.

```
import numpy as np 
from imagecodecs import (
    jpeg2k_encode, jpeg2k_decode, jpeg2k_check, jpeg2k_version, JPEG2K
)


array = np.load("data.npy")
compressed_channels = []

for channel in array:

    compressed_channel = jpeg2k_encode(channel, level=0)
    compressed_channels.append(compressed_channel)


np.save("data"+"_compressed.npy", compressed_channels)

compressed_channels = np.load("data"+"_compressed.npy")

decompressed_channels = []
for compressed_channel in compressed_channels:
    decompressed_channel = jpeg2k_decode(compressed_channel)
    decompressed_channels.append(decompressed_channel)

decoded = np.array(decompressed_channels)


compression_ratio = array.nbytes / sum(len(c) for c in compressed_channels)

print(np.array_equal(decoded, array))

print("Original array size (bytes):", array.nbytes)
print("Compressed array size (bytes):", sum(len(c) for c in compressed_channels))
print("Compression ratio:", compression_ratio)


np.save("data"+"_decompressed.npy", decoded)
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Hi @Marco , could you share a small piece of code to generate an example of the multi-spectral images you are using? It might make things easier for StackOverflow users to help you.

Comment: Yep, like said above, trying to compress an entirely random chunk of data won't give you any meaningful metrics, no matter which algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem and all that).

Comment: Normally the channels of multi-spectral data are very highly correlated with one another so something that compresses across the channels, rather than down the rows or across the columns should maybe tend to do better.

Comment: @MarkSetchell IOW, in plain Numpy terms: `np.transpose(data, (1, 2, 0))` or similar before trying to compress it..? :)

Comment: And @MarcoLoBartolo – a screenshot of a 2D matrix of numbers really doesn't help much here :)

Comment: Turning the matrix into a 2d matrix did not give me any particular benefit, I try to post the data.

Comment: In case you are not limited to a common compression method, consider one of the many [hyperspectral image compression algorithms](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/optical-engineering/volume-59/issue-09/090902/Comprehensive-review-of-hyperspectral-image-compression-algorithms/10.1117/1.OE.59.9.090902.full)

Comment: @AKX I'm not sure I can get my head around the Numpy way, but I mean that PNG for example looks at the pixel above and to the left as a filter/predictor of the current pixel, i.e. it looks around the pixel to compress spatially. I was trying to get at looking at the radiometrically adjacent pixels as predictors, i.e. adjacent bands. So not pixel (x-1,y-1) but pixel (sameX,sameY,nextChannel).

Comment: @cgohlke I thank you, I had already seen that paper but unfortunately for me to implement such an algorithm is a bit complex, I would like to be able to find a library to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only compression method I could find that yields a compression ratio greater than 1.5 for the provided 16-bit, 31 channel image is JPEG-XL, but only if the channels are treated as a spatial dimension, e.g. the (C, Y, X) image is stored as Y frames of X, C images:

```
import os
import numpy
import imagecodecs
data = numpy.load('data.npy')
data = numpy.moveaxis(data, 0, -1)
imagecodecs.imwrite('data.jxl', data)
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(data, imagecodecs.imread('data.jxl'))
print(data.nbytes / os.path.getsize('data.jxl'))

1.536
```

JPEG-XL is a relatively new format. There are not too many software/libraries that can read it. For comparison, the runner-ups JPEG 2000 and (surprisingly) LZMA are around 1.3, APNG at 1.22.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing, sir!